# How to notify users about app update which is not no play store

Tags: java, android, webview

I've a webview app which is not on play store yet.
What would be some ways to prompt or notify users about the new updates..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you made any updates to the app, you can send a push notification to the app users through Google Cloud Messaging service.. GCM is a free services that you can get from the Google.

Form more information for GCM https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm#arch

You can use a small portal to send a push notification, if you want to do it manually. Use a small PHP script that calls for push notification, when you want to send notification.

If your app is hosted in a sever other than playsore, u can update the app with new version of the app... So users will be able to get new version of the app..

Answer (score 0):

1. You can call your own API on first screen of application with which you can compare your latest version with application version, if it's not updated, show popup of update to users. Your API should give you latest application version so that you can compare it corrcectly.
2. Another way is push notification, whenever you are updating application, fire notification which will send update detail to all current users.